# FTP download backgroundworker

Tags: c#, ftp

I have this code but it's not working...

The progressbar is not moving and the downloaded file size is 0kb.

I think I have some problem in my WHILE loop! How can I solve this problem? Please give me instructions!

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  DirectoryInfo folder= new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Cloud24");
  try
  {
    {
      long size= 0;
      WebClient request = new WebClient();
      request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userid, userpass);
      FileStream file = File.Create(folder+ "//" + downloadname);
      byte[] filedata = request.DownloadData(ftpadress + "/" + downloadname);
      while ((size= file.Read(filedata, 0, filedata.Length)) > 0) 
      {
        file.Write(filedata, 0, filedata.Length);
        size += (int)filedata.Length;
        double dProgressPercentage = ((double)(size) / (double)filedata.Length);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)(dProgressPercentage * 100));
      }
      file.Close();
      MessageBox.Show(downloadname + " downloaded!" + 
                      Environment.NewLine + "There: " + folder);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + exc.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Comment: is it going inside th while loop?

Comment: It generate the file but the size is only 0kb.

Comment: your code doesn't really make sense. When you download the file, you do that in a blocking call. Once that is finished, you already have all the contents in memory and there's really nothing to report on. Granted, if the file is big, you could report on writing the actual file to disk, but your program doesn't enter the while loop because you try to read the file before you write it. Question is, why would you do that?

Comment: Really. And what is your suggestion for solve this error?

Comment: Have a look at my solution in my post underneath here

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work, but I haven't actually tested it.

```
    private async void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var folder = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Cloud24");
        try
        {
            {
                var manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim();
                var client = new WebClient { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userid, userpass) };
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, args) => backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(args.ProgressPercentage);
                client.DownloadDataCompleted += (o, args) => manualResetEvent.Set();
                var filedata = client.DownloadDataAsync(ftpadress + "/" + downloadname);
                manualResetEvent.Wait();
                using (var stream = File.Create(folder + "//" + downloadname))
                {
                    await stream.WriteAsync(filedata, 0, filedata.Length);
                }
                MessageBox.Show(downloadname + " downloaded!" + Environment.NewLine + "There: " + folder);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: var filedata = client.DownloadDataAsync(ftpadress + "/" + downloadname); throw and error about the wrong URI.

Comment: Well...what does ftpadress + "/" + downloadname evaluate to? You need to make sure that it evaluates to a valid ftp address.

Comment: forexample ftp://contoso.com/testfile.txt. The ftpadress is "ftp://contoso.com" and the downloadname is the "testfile.txt"

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any extra / or something similiar? Basically the error says it the URI is not valid or the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Well...it's something wrong with the evaluated expression. You are 100% sure the file exists on the FTP server? Maybe missing a path to it or something. Basically the client can't find it, so nothing really I can do about that.